# Scalable table sorting approach

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sorting, html-table

I want to sort each column in react. I can do it, but forcing the code, for example if I have this array and display it in a html table, I want when I click id it sort in ascending order, when I click name it sort in ascending order and when click again it sort descending order, i want the same with name and age. And at the same time i want an arrow that if that column is in ascendig is looking up otherwise is looking down.

```js
const USERS = [
  { id: 1, name: "Andy", age: 32 },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 30 },
  { id: 3, name: "Tom Hulk", age: 40 },
  { id: 4, name: "Tom Hank", age: 50 },
  { id: 5, name: "Audra", age: 30 },
  { id: 6, name: "Anna", age: 68 },
  { id: 7, name: "Tom", age: 34 },
  { id: 8, name: "Tom Riddle", age: 28 },
  { id: 9, name: "Bolo", age: 23 },
];
```

The way that i can do it is like this, but it's ugly and not practical. And also, when i change the sort state for the arrow, it updates for all the arrow not for the arrow of the column that i clicked

```js
  const sortBy = (k) => {
    if (k === "id") {
      if (sort) {
        const res = USERS.sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1));
        setDataFilter(res);
        setSort(!sort);
        console.log(res);
      } else {
        const res = USERS.sort((a, b) => (a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1));
        setDataFilter(res);
        setSort(!sort);
        console.log(res);
      }
    } else if (k === "age") {
      if (sort) {
        const res = USERS.sort((a, b) => (a.age > b.age ? 1 : -1));
        setDataFilter(res);
        setSort(!sort);
        console.log(res);
      } else {
        const res = USERS.sort((a, b) => (a.age < b.agek ? 1 : -1));
        setDataFilter(res);
        setSort(!sort);
        console.log(res);
      }
    } else if (k === "name") {
      if (sort) {
        const res = USERS.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        setDataFilter(res);
        setSort(!sort);
        console.log(res);
      } else {
        const res = USERS.sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name));
        setDataFilter(res);
        setSort(!sort);
        console.log(res);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("hmm");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Just write a function that accepts params for the property you want to sort by and type of sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. It checks the type of the sorting key value and choose the sorting method accordingly. I re-used your logic to make it simple for you.

```
const USERS = [
  { id: 1, name: "Andy", age: 32 },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 30 },
  { id: 3, name: "Tom Hulk", age: 40 },
  { id: 4, name: "Tom Hank", age: 50 },
  { id: 5, name: "Audra", age: 30 },
  { id: 6, name: "Anna", age: 68 },
  { id: 7, name: "Tom", age: 34 },
  { id: 8, name: "Tom Riddle", age: 28 },
  { id: 9, name: "Bolo", age: 23 },
];
 
 
const sortBy = (k, sort) => {
     var res;
     if( USERS[0] && (typeof USERS[0][k] == 'string')) {
          res = sort ? USERS.sort((a, b) => a[k].localeCompare(b[k])) : USERS.sort((a, b) => b[k].localeCompare(a[k]));
     } else {
         const f = sort ? 1 : -1;
         res = USERS.sort((a, b) => (a[k] > b[k] ? f : -f));
     }
     // setDataFilter(res);
     // setSort(!sort);
     console.log(res);
}
 
sortBy('name', 1);
sortBy('age', 1);
sortBy('name', 0);
sortBy('age', 0);
```

Comment: Inferring type from value may cause certain unexpected results with number-like strings, which happens pretty often. I.e. for `id` values `['1', '2', '3', '10', 21']` sorted in ascending order you will get `['1', '10', '2', '21', '3']`.

Comment: Year IDs can be string too. Its usually depends on what data the api will return and the response json parsing in this case would not be numeric values as string I'm sure of it. And if its type is string then '10' should be smaller than '2'. Anyways it all depends on data and accordingly the code can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have sorting callbacks within a mapping object (by property name or by property type).

Also, do not forget to leverage [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)/ [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hooks to boost sorting performance through memoizing the sorting output (which may be beneficial for large number of items):

```js
const users = [
        { id: 1, name: "Andy", age: 32 },
        { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 30 },
        { id: 3, name: "Tom Hulk", age: 40 },
        { id: 4, name: "Tom Hank", age: 50 },
        { id: 5, name: "Audra", age: 30 },
        { id: 6, name: "Anna", age: 68 },
        { id: 7, name: "Tom", age: 34 },
        { id: 8, name: "Tom Riddle", age: 28 },
        { id: 9, name: "Bolo", age: 23 },
      ],
      
      sortDirection = {
        'asc': 1,
        'desc': -1
      },
      
      numericSorter = propName => 
          sortOrder => 
            ({[propName]:a}, {[propName]:b}) => 
              (a-b)*sortDirection[sortOrder],
              
      stringicSorter = propName => 
          sortOrder => 
            ({[propName]:a}, {[propName]:b}) => 
              a.localeCompare(b)*sortDirection[sortOrder],
      
      sortMap = {
        id: numericSorter('id'),
        name: stringicSorter('name'),
        age: numericSorter('age')
      },
      
      sortUsers = (users, byProp, sortOrder) => 
        users.sort(sortMap[byProp](sortOrder))
        
console.log(sortUsers(users, 'name', 'desc'))
console.log(sortUsers(users, 'age', 'asc'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%;}
```